# php array not forming properly

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Initial javascript to get a string/array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table").tableDnD({
    onDrop: function(table, row){
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
            var debugStr = "";
            for (var i=1; i<rows.length; i++) {
                debugStr += rows[i].id+":";
                //debugStr += rows[i].id;
            }
        data = debugStr; // colon seperated
        }
    });
});
function sendData()
{
    var packed = ""; // Initialize packed or we get the word 'undefined'
    for (i = 0; (i < data.length); i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        packed += ",";
        }
    packed += escape(data[i]);
        }
    document.data.data.value = packed;
    document.data.submit();
}
</script>
```

Now in the PHP...

Return my array/string from post:

```
$packed = $_POST['data'];
$data = split(":", $packed);
for ($i = 0; ($i < count($data)); $i++) {
  $data[$i] = rawurldecode($data[$i]);
  $data[$i] = str_replace(",", "", $data[$i]);
  $data[$i] = str_replace(":", ",", $data[$i]);
}
```

create an array from it:

```
$arrayUpdated = array();
foreach($data as $value) {
    print_r($value);
    $arrayUpdated[] = $value;
    }
```

which returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 9,8,6,5,4,3,2,15,1,0, )
```

when I was expecting:

```
Array ( [0] => 9, [1] => 8, [2] => 6, [3] => 5, [4] => 4, [5] => 3, [6] => 2, [7] => 15, [8] => 1, [9] => 0, )
```

what have I got wrong?
Thanks,
Andy

Comment: What happens if you do print_r($packed) straight after it intercepts the POST array?

Comment: er... so `sendData` inserts a comma after each character in `data`?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using JQuery already, wouldn't it be easier to send the data in JSON format rather than manually building it into a colon/comma separated and then manually spliting it apart in PHP?

In your JS page, replace most of your `sendData()` function with a call to `$.toJSON(data);`:

```
function sendData() {
    document.data.data.value = $.toJson(data);
    document.data.submit();
}
```

In your PHP code, simlpy use `json_decode()` to load your data into an array with exactly the same structure as you had in Javascript.

```
$data=json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($data);
```

*Note: you may need an extra JQuery plugin to get the `toJSON()` method -- See http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ for more info.

Comment: edited to include code examples and a link to where you can get the $.toJSON() plug-in.

Comment: nice one, i'm going to have a go at putting this in, it should simplify my code a fair bit. cheers!

Comment: Tried this, nothing showing up...
I've got the 'jquery.json-2.2.js' include correctly linked in.
I inserted a js alert to check contents of 'data' (its all in there) then when the posted page is returned and I do:
$data=json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($data);
nothing shows, any ideas why?

Comment: Okay, so the JQuery JSON encode side is working. That's good. Have you checked the contents of $_POST before doing `json_decode()`? If that's blank then it's presumably the form that isn't posting correctly. I took the `document.data.data.value` and `document.data.submit` directly from your original code, so its possible they may not be correct. Try checking them in Firebug (or a similar browser debugging tool).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer- but if you need a quick fix you could do (in PHP):

```
// if $myarray=Array ( [0] => 9,8,6,5,4,3,2,15,1,0, ) ;

$myarray=explode(",",$myarray[0]);
```

Also, note that the [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) function is deprecated in PHP 5.3.0, you can replace with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: This did the trick for how I had it, but ended up using JSON as above instead.